# WatiN, VBScript

Tags: testing, watin

I am using [WatiN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir#WatiN) for my web tests. In one of my web pages, I have a VBScript function which opens a dialogbox. I am unable to access it using WatiN.

I tried using WatiNTestRecorder; it was unsuccessful.

I tried this also:
http://blogs.dovetailsoftware.com/blogs/kmiller/archive/2008/07/16/scenario-testing-with-watin.aspx, unsuccessful again.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the VbScriptMsgBoxDialogHandler? Following an example

```
        var handler = new VbScriptMsgBoxDialogHandler(buttonToPush);
    using(new UseDialogOnce(Ie.DialogWatcher, handler ))
    {
        Ie.Button("vbScriptMsgBox").ClickNoWait();
        handler.WaitUntilHandled(10);

                Assert.That(handler.HasHandledDialog, "Should have handled dialog");                
    }
```